# Understanding the null coalescing operator

Tags: c#, .net

I will appreciate a logical explanation to this line of code. What will it achieve?

```
x = y ?? "";
```

where `x` is of type object and `y` is string variable.

Please note that the program compiled.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)? What haven't you understood? _" It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand"_

Comment: You should search or try something before asking here. Here is detailed documentation by msdn. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: This is no ternary operator, and I'm not sure why you'd think so. `?:`, as in `x?y:z`, is often called a ternary operator because it has three operands. That's what ternary means. It doesn't mean any other operator involving a question mark is also ternary.

Answer (score 5):

it will assign an empty string to x if y is null

it is called [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

for example if you have

```
a = b ?? c ?? d ?? e ?? f;
```

then it will look for `b` value. if it is not null then `a=b`
if `b` is null it will check for `c` value. if it is not null then `a=c`.
if `c` is null also then it will check for ... (go on)

Answer (score 2):

This translates into the long statement.

```
if(y != null)
{
   x = y;
}
else
{
   x = "";
}
```